# Count frequency of words in mutiple csv files without stopwords

Tags: python, pyspark, words, stop-words, word-frequency

I would like to count the occurence of the words in several csv files. First I would like to show 10 most occuring words with stop words then without the stop words.

This is my code:

```
import nltk
nltk.download("stopwords")


from nltk.corpus import stopwords


myfile = sc.textFile('./Sacramento*.csv')


counts = myfile.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda word: (word, 1)).reduceByKey(lambda v1,v2: v1 + v2)


sorted_counts = counts.map(lambda (a, b): (b, a)).sortByKey(0, 1).map(lambda (a, b): (b, a))


first_ten = sorted_counts.take(10)


first_ten
Out[7]:
[(u'Residential', 917),
 (u'2', 677),
 (u'CA', 597),
 (u'3', 545),
 (u'SACRAMENTO', 439),
 (u'ours', 388),
 (u'0', 387),
 (u'4', 277),
 (u'Mon May 19 00:00:00 EDT 2008', 268),
 (u'Fri May 16 00:00:00 EDT 2008', 264)]


cachedStopWords = stopwords.words("english")


result_ll = counts.map(lambda (a, b): (b, a)).sortByKey(0,
1).map(lambda (a, b): (b, a))


print [i for i in result_ll.take(10) if i not in cachedStopWords]
```

But the output is still with stop words - "ours" is also between stopwords

[(u'Residential', 917), (u'2', 677), (u'CA', 597), (u'3', 545), (u'SACRAMENTO', 439), (u'ours', 388), (u'0', 387), (u'4', 277), (u'Mon May 19 00:00:00 EDT 2008', 268), (u'Fri May 16 00:00:00 EDT 2008', 264)]

How should I change my code so output is without stop word: "ours"?

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in the last line, it should be like

```
print [i for i in result_ll.take(10) if i[0] not in cachedStopWords]
```

because `i[0]` holds the actual word.